# Get a list of YouTube Music library uploads

Tags: web-scraping, youtube, youtube-api

I need to get a list of all albums of my YouTube Music uploads library. How to manage that?

- The uploads are at: https://music.youtube.com/library/uploaded_albums
- An album URL looks like this:
  https://music.youtube.com/browse/FEmusic_library_privately_owned_release_detailb_po_CNyreqpr-ZLpYRIuMCBzaG93IGF0IHRoZTAgeWVhcno3JlIgNncG0MdG91Y2hlIGFtb

Comment: Did you try with standard http rest Apis provided by google?

Comment: @JRichardsz Can you please share the link. I didn't found any for _YouTube Music Library Uploads_. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to use ytmusicapi, it has everything you need.

https://github.com/sigma67/ytmusicapi

https://ytmusicapi.readthedocs.io/

Full disclosure: I am the author.

For reference, you can use [get_library_upload_albums](https://ytmusicapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#ytmusicapi.YTMusic.get_library_upload_albums) to get a full list of upload albums.

Gets the albums of uploaded songs in the user’s library.
Parameters:

```
limit – Number of albums to return. Default: 25
order – Order of albums to return. Allowed values: ‘a_to_z’, ‘z_to_a’, ‘recently_added’. Default: Default order.
```

Returns:

List of albums as returned by get_library_albums()

Answer (score 1):

According to this 2018/2019:  https://support.google.com/youtubemusic/thread/191756?hl=en

> YouTube Music launched only a few weeks ago. At this point, there's no YouTube Music specific API available, but if YouTube decides to release one, you will probably find it on the Google Developers pages.

As you and others said, I think there is not rest api available. Be careful, maybe is a beta product and could be deprecated in any moment.

Anyway, if youtube music library does not publish an api, want it or not, must be using a kind of api to show information in its web page.

If we inspect its home page https://music.youtube.com/tasteprofile, we can see several ajax requests. And one of them is:

https://music.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/music/get_search_suggestions?alt=json&key=AI***YFDNX30

With this request headers

```
Host: music.youtube.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1125
X-Goog-Visitor-Id: Cgs**D
X-Goog-AuthUser: 0
X-Goog-PageId: null
x-origin: https://music.youtube.com
X-YouTube-Client-Name: 67
X-YouTube-Client-Version: 0.1
X-Youtube-Identity-Token: QUFFLUh***lRDR5Z3w=
Origin: https://music.youtube.com
Authorization: SAPISIDHASH 159***efb5c
Referer: https://music.youtube.com/tasteprofile
```

In which we can see **X-Youtube-Identity-Token**. So if you find how to get this token, you could consume some endpoints used in music.youtube.com.

Here some resources in which you can see how **X-Youtube-Identity-Token** is used for example to get : **YouTube autoplay suggested videos**. So I think, [Youtube Api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs) is used:

- https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/29451-youtube-search-while-watching-video/code
- https://github.com/Tatsh/youtube-unofficial
- https://gist.github.com/manciuszz/eef680b89bfe04e6c293b88cb3b10d08